# Heroku app does not respond at all anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Eventually a request to access the app will timeout within the browser.

Nothing was changed to the app. Yet suddenly it went down several hours ago.

The heroku logs show no attempt being made to request it.

I can restart it, and deploy to it, yet nothing changes.

I assumed maybe a service is causing this, but I stripped it of any 3rd party vendor calls and it still doesn't respond to me trying to access the site.

Does anyone have any insightful ideas on where to go from here? I'm sorry for how vague this question is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your DNS down? use host command to check it or visit the app using *.herokuapp.com

Comment: Blam! It *WAS* my DNS. Thank you so much!